# How to get user email id , user name from Facebook in android

Tags: android, facebook, twitter

I want to get user email id, user name from Facebook without using Facebook SDK. Actually i did  Facebook and Twitter sharing using Nostra library . But now i need Facebook and Twitter user email id, user name , etc. . If i use Facebook and Twitter SDK , my code will be useless because i used Nostra library .

Now in this condition , what should i do ?. If there are any way to solve this problem ,

```
Please help me .
Thanks in advance .
```

Answer (score 0):

For getting email you can use user.getProperty("email").toString();

Answer (score -1):

If you want to access data which is restricted, you'll need to gather the appropriate permissions by building a manual login flow for your Facebook app. Have a look here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v2.0